# Sending emails from different columns google scripting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So Im using a Spreadsheet and making and script for it to automatically (daily) send an update to one particular mail address, the spreadsheet daily updates itself and I already have the desired information on the first sheet, so there is no problem with that, problem is sending this update.

I have 5 columns (increments daily), but I want to take the whole information from columns 1,2 and the last column and send it through an email as a table, but just these 3 columns, not anything else. I know I need to handle arrays (or at least that is what Im thinking), but I am always getting undefined. Here's what I got on the email module:

```
function EmailScript() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var lcol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var rowA;
  var rangoA = sheet.getRange(1, lrow);
  var datita = rangoA.getValues();
  for(i in datita){
    var row = datita[i];
    var message = "Hey " + row[1] + ",\n how are you doing today?";  
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "pruebas", message);

 }
```

Perhaps, I need to append the answer? I want to display all information, not just the first one...

I know I am making some stupid mistake but truth is, I dont know what.

Thanks!

Comment: Thought Excel had some similarities and probably this issue has been solved for Excel.

Comment: Could you show an example of the sheet and email?

Answer (score 0):

- The first declare your `var message = '';` before the `for`
- Then rewrite the row without `var`

  ```
  message += "Hey " + row[1] + ",\n how are you doing today?\n";
  ```